# Why differ the definition of the tensor product in algebraic and analysis books?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

In algebraic books, Tensor product is defined using quotient space and in analysis books, tensor product is defined using the bilinear map and linear functional.
Why is it defined in two ways?
Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: It doesn't matter. All you will use is the universal property of the tensor product anyways.

Comment: Because different definitions are more convenient in different settings and reflect how the author approaches a concept.

Comment: Exercise for the reader: explore whether those two definitions are equivalent or not, or if they are equivalent under some conditions.

Comment: Additionally to what's been said above, when defining an object via a universal property, one needs to check that such an object actually exists by constructing it somehow.

Comment: Different definitions are already given in a book on abstract algebra, or linear algebra.